# Does the deprecation of Github password authentication include all methods of Basic Authentication via curl?

Tags: github

I have been authenticating to GitHub with the following:

```
curl -u username:token https://api.github.com/user
```

In [this GitHub blog post mentioning the deprecation of using user passwords](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-password-auth/) it mentions:

> Instead, use a personal access token when testing endpoints or doing
> local development:
>
> curl -H 'Authorization: token my_access_token'
> https://api.github.com/user/repos

This method is via the *Authorization* header. They did not mention here that providing a **token** via Basic Authentication with the `-u` argument would still be possible.

Can anyone clear this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I posted the above question to GitHub support and received the following reply in relation to the GitHub blog post example:

> This method is via the Authorization header. They did not mention here
> that providing a token via Basic Authentication with the -u argument
> would still be possible.
>
> While we have deprecated password authentication to the GitHub API, we
> have no current plans to deprecate basic authentication, so you are
> correct— API calls can still be authenticated using the -u switch in
> curl, provided a personal access token is used in place of a password.
> This syntax is outlined in our Other authentication methods
> documentation.
>
> However, our recommended method of authenticating with the GitHub API
> is through supplying the token in an authorization header, so this is
> how we provide curl examples throughout our REST and GraphQL API
> documentation.
>
> So, while using the -u switch isn't the primary documented method of
> authentication, please feel free to continue to do so if this is your
> preferred syntax.

So in conclusion, providing a **token** via Basic Authentication with the -u argument is still supported as of Feb 2021. However, it isn't the primary documented auth method.